# After update to react 18, enzyme library's mount function is throwing error - TypeError: Cannot read property '_reactInternals' of null

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, jest-enzyme

I have upgraded react from 17.0.2 to 18.2.0. I have also added enzyme adapter: https://github.com/cfaester/enzyme-adapter-react-18. However, the mount function in enzyme is throwing the error: **TypeError: Cannot read property '_reactInternals' of null.**
The error is thrown whether I pass a component to mount function as:

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
 component = mount(
        <SomeComponent> </SomeComponent>
      );
```

or some html as:

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
 component = mount(
        <div>...</div>
      );
```

In setupTests.js file, I have used the adapter as:

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from '@cfaester/enzyme-adapter-react-18';
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

Could anyone tell me how I can solve this issue?